# Closed form for a summation.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Mathematica says $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{n^k} = \dfrac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{n^n}$. I would like to know how to show this equality.

The left hand side is the solution to a probability problem:  Select integers (with replacement) from {1,2,...,n} until the cumulative sum of your selected integers is at least n.  What is the probability that your cumulative sum is exactly n?  The right hand side is the ratio of labeled trees on n+1 nodes to functions from [n] into [n].  A combinatorial proof to the equations would be great.  I would settle for an analytic proof.

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Expand $(n+1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: @ Yves Daoust.   Yes  Thank you.  I see it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Binomial Theorem we get as a series expansion for $(n+1)^{n-1}$ the following

$$(1+n)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}n^{n-1-k}$$

By applying the index shift $k'=k+1$ - and therefore $k=k'-1$ - we further get

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}n^{n-1-k}=\sum_{k'=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k'-1}n^{n-k'}$$

One may note that within the term $n^{n-k'}$ the $n^n$ is independed of the index. By reshaping the whole equality we get

$$\begin{align}
(1+n)^{n-1}&=\sum_{k'=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k'-1}n^{n-k'}\\
&=n^n\sum_{k'=1}^{n}\frac{\binom{n-1}{k'-1}}{n^{k'}}\\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{(1+n)^{n-1}}{n^n}&=\sum_{k'=1}^{n}\frac{\binom{n-1}{k'-1}}{n^{k'}}
\end{align}$$

which is your desired result.